# Remote text mode terminal shell "screen"

Tags: ssh, background-process

I know it is possible to have remote VNC screen on server and connect to it and see, what is happening there.

Is it possible to have the same in text-mode shell?

I would connect to remote machine with ssh, then connect to such "remote screen" and see, what my program does there?

The general task is following:

I have python script, that is scrapping the web. This script just prints what it does to stdout. Currently I am running the script in ssh terminal. From time to time I am switching to ssh window and see, how my script feels: either it is still working, or it is crashed with error report.

But in this situation, if I reboot my machine or network disconnect, my ssh session will quit and all containin programs will stop.

How to avoid this? How to have something like text-mode VNC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for `screen` program. It should do what you want.

Alternatively you can run your program with `nohup` so it will not die when you disconnect your session (later on you can see the output in nohup.out file)

Comment: Even I guessed it's name :)

Comment: This answer should probably also mention `tmux` which is somewhat more versatile and modern.

Comment: IMO nor screen not any other utility are necessary as all the work can be done with sample process management tools like `&`, `nohup` and redirects

Answer (score 1):

You can use few tricks which can help you

1. Put the script in background with `&` at the end
2. Deattach the background script from terminal with `nohup` command
3. Redirect the STDOUT and STDERR to files to be able to monitor the
   progress like

`nohup program >stdout.log 2>stderr.log &`

So you will be able to monitor the progress as well if problem occur and program crash